# Fake high scores in Unikong?

Tags: discussion, unikong

All other high scores in UNIKONG game are multiples of 10000.

[image]

Is this pure coincidence or these scores are fake?

Comment: The highscores are not shared in any way, they are pre-programmed.

Comment: So 40000 high score means it's highest achievable score..:P

Comment: Nope, I scored higher than that. :P

Comment: Anybody completed this game(reached to last level)...:P

Comment: You know they're fake because #1 isn't ASS

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Those are the initial scores, pre-set before anyone played the game.

This is something that was done in all arcade machines back in the day, so the leaderboard wasn't empty on startup.

Comment: I'm still disappointed that beating JON didn't earn me a *nerd sniped* bronze badge.

Comment: @nwp - I'm disappointed that beating JON didn't raise JON's score to something higher than what I reached.

Comment: @nwp: you're *lucky* that beating JON didn't call the wrath of the nerd gods down upon your head! :-)